# How to connect and push a file to informatica using Python

Tags: python, etl, informatica

I need to connect to informatica server using python and push a file to a folder. I've looked up on the internet and found little info regarding the library "infa" (https://github.com/kradecki/infa).

This is the code I found on that page:

```
import infa

# Create Pmrep class instance and open a connection to the repository
p = infa.Pmrep(
    '/opt/informatica/9.6.1/server/bin/pmrep',
    r='Repository_Name',
    h='localhost',
    o='6005',
    n='admin',
    x='secret_password'
)

# Get a list of all aggregator transformations in the "Demo" folder
a = p.listobjects(o='transformation', t='aggregator', f='Demo')
print(a)

# Close connections and cleanup
p.cleanup()
```

However, there is not much info on it. Looks like the github page seems inactive.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Please help!

Comment: Can you please provide proper details. Is your server where do  you have file is same as informatica server. Or you have two different server where your file is  in one server and informatica in another server?

Comment: Please go into informatica metadata and run some SQLs. Connecting it through inforomatica user, repo password may not be a good idea to get data. Because informatica can always restrict what they want to open and what not. You can go through this link to see the tables and their structures - https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/4/PC_100_RepositoryGuide_en.pdf

Comment: I don't understand the goal. What does "push a file to a folder" mean? Can you give an example? I'm not even sure if you refer the Informatica folders or OS folders - or if you need Informatica to perform some OS actions.